# Generalization of hypergraphs with edges to edges (and relationship to higher categories)?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, higher-category-theory, hypergraphs

For some authors, it seems that hypergraphs allow or do not allow edges on edges, but it's hard to find a lot of literature on the topic. I am wondering if hypergraphs with edges on edges had a specific name, or what to look for in literature.

Also, I can see this kind of recursive structures in other areas of maths, the first two that comes to mind being:

- Higher categories with (n+1) morphisms on (n) morphisms
- Polytopes with (n+1)-dimensional faces built upon (n)-dimensional faces (3D cell -> 2D faces -> 1D edge -> 0D vertex)

My questions are:

1. Is there any literature on hypergraphs with edges on edges?
2. Do they have a specific name?
3. Is there any general abstraction for recursive structures in maths like hypergraphs with edges on edges/higher categories/polytopes?

Comment: I am curious what reference allows for a hyperedge to be a set of 2-sets. The common definition of a hypergraph is a collection of vertices together with a collection of edges, which are subsets of vertices. I do not know if there is a name for the type of object you are describing.